Using forming tap to reform eyeglasses female thread
The 1.4mm bore thread of an eyeglasses worn-out,so the screw get loose after some time.I would like to use 1.5mm screw(instead of the original 1.4mm)to fix the problem.
Can i use 1.5mm forming tap(reform the thread)and fit 1.5mm screw,but without drilling/enlarging the hole before the forming tap action or i must enlarge the bore?
The minor diameter of the 1.5mm forming tap is only 0.075mm larger than the bore size.

The barrel that you're tapping into is also very thin. Have you tried threadlock or something similar?

May you relate to the professional part,please?I am not looking for advices how to fix the eyeglasses,i am looking for explanation about the forming thread issue.

These are my thoughts; not an authorative answer.
When you are using a cutting tap, the tap removes material in the form of small chips. This means that the bore size can be the same size as the internal diameter of the tap.
When you are using a forming tap, no material is removed; it is displaced, which makes for a smoother thread. In this case the bore size would need to be larger than the internal diameter of the tap. There has to be space for that material to be moved into.
This is the information I found on McMaster Carr website.
For an M1.6x0.35 thread you need a 1.25mm bore for a cutting thread tap link, but a 1.42mm bore for a forming tap. link
So I think that if the present bore is smaller than that of the forming tap you will not succeed.
Even though the original tap has removed some material already and you are forming thread of the same pitch I do not think that there will be enough space for the forming tap to be able to function especially as the present bore is smaller than the internal tap diameter.

Thanks Rich,you clear my doubt.I see that the 0.075mm(forming tap minor diameter larger than the bore)is a problem with forming tap.I would use the cutting tap,but using electric drill with very thin drill bit to enlarge this small delicate hole is not going to end well.But okay,as i mentioned before,my main goal was to understand the rules of the forming/cutting tap process in that situation.Thanks again.

recutting threads that fine is a pain. the taps are hard to find and very easily broken. @Rich's answer (using thread-locking adhesive) is your best bet: easy and cheaper by far than buying a tap.

To make things clear,I am talking about REFORMING the thread,not recutting it.DKNguyen gave me(on other thread)a great professional explanation about reforming the thread and i just needed an advice(further to its answer) in regard to the M1.5 forming tap,whether i can use it without enlarge the bore or not,as the 1.4 forming tap screws into the bore too easily(i gave you a very specific details for that).Applying thread lock is not professional answer and it is not related to my question.I hope that DKNguyen can help.

I understand what you are saying. However, thread lock IS used by professionals and manufacturers whenever a critical bolt must not come loose, by, for example, vibration. Instructions from the manufacturer for bolt replacement indicates required torque and the use of thread lock.

@Rich,Thanks for your answer,but i would like to mention that fixing this specific eyeglasses is not my main goal.My interest is to know/learn the engineer rules about reforming threads.The fixing itself is negligible.So,Can i use 1.5mm forming tap(to reform the 1.4mm worn thread)and fit 1.5mm screw,but without drilling/enlarging the hole before the forming tap action or i must enlarge the bore?
